# Rhino Mocks Stub Method not working

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks, stub

Why won't this test method work?  I keep getting requires a return value or an exception to throw.

```
public AuthenticateResponse Authenticate(string username, string password)
        {
            string response = GetResponse(GetUrl(username, password).ToString());

            return ParseResponse(response);
        }


        [TestMethod()]
        [ExpectedException(typeof(XmlException))]
        public void Authenticate_BadXml_ReturnException()
        {
            MockRepository mockRepository = new MockRepository();
            SSO sso = mockRepository.Stub<SSO>();

            sso.Stub(t => t.GetResponse("")).Return("<test>d");

            AuthenticateResponse response = sso.Authenticate("test", "test");
        }
```

Comment: Is the `GetResponse` method virtual?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your repository is still in "record" mode.  You're mixing record/replay semantics (the "old" way of doing things) with the newer AAA (arrange/act/assert) style.

Instead of creating your own repository, simply use:

```
var sso = MockRepository.GeneateStub<SSO>();
```

Everything should work fine now.

Comment: That fixed that error but now it isn't hitting the Parse method, but is mocking the GetResponse method.  I added the actual method above.  Is it overriding the Parse method?

Comment: return ParseResponse(response);

Comment: Ah, ok.  So it looks like what you want to do is partial mocking (since you want to stub out some part of the class but run the real code in another part).  It's been a while since I did this in Rhino.Mocks, but you'll need to use PartialMock, make sure GetResponse() is virtual and make sure GetUrl(username, password) returns an empty string (which is how you defined your Stub call).  Or, if you don't care about the args, use .IgnoreArguments() after the Stub call.

Answer (score 1):

Your last line is calling the `Authenticate` method on your stub object, you haven't set up a return or value or exception to throw when calling it, so Rhino Mocks doesn't know what the stub should do and it causes an error.  You probably don't want to call a method on your stub - that seems kind of pointless to me, is there another object (that you're actually testing in this test) that you should be calling a method on?

Comment: I guess I am using it wrong.  The authenticate method makes a call to an external service and gets data back.  I want to mimic that with <test>d and send it to the Parse method that is also in authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

Is that your whole test?  If so, your test makes no sense.  The only object in your test is the one you're stubbing--where is the subject of the test?

If you're trying to test the SSO class, you *absolutely never* want to mock/stub it.  If SSO has one or more dependencies, use the mocking framework to set up canned interactions between those dependencies and your SUT.  That is the exact purpose of a mocking framework.

Comment: I guess I should just test the parse method directly instead of the authenticate method itself.  My dependency is the HTTP request which I am trying to remove.